# pandas dataframe groupby a number of rows

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

If you have a pandas `DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})` is there a simple way to group it into groups of 3 or any number?

I understand this can be done by adding an extra column that contains values to allow grouping, for example you could join the above DataFrame to `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]` and groupby the added column. But it seems like it shouldn't be necessary to add an extra column for this operation.

Also I could create a array of indexes `np.linspace(0,9,4)` and loop over the array values using them as parameters to the DataFrame.ix[]  but that doesn't seem fast for large DataFrames.

Am I missing a simpler way?

**==Solution==**

From the answers below my preferred solution is to use [numpy.array_split](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) ( it doesn't raise an exception if an unequal division is made unlike numpy.split ), you can also pass an array of indexes to split on rather than the number of resulting pieces desired. With the line below you can split a DataFrame (df) into smaller DataFrames of x rows

```
split_df = np.array_split(df, np.arange(0, len(df),x))
```

The split_df is a list where the first object is an empty numpy array and the following objects are the split DataFrames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another method that use `numpy.split` or `numpy.array_split`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":np.arange(9), "B":np.arange(10, 19)}, 
                  index=np.arange(100, 109))
for tmp in np.split(df, 3):
    print tmp
```

the output is:

```
     A   B
100  0  10
101  1  11
102  2  12
     A   B
103  3  13
104  4  14
105  5  15
     A   B
106  6  16
107  7  17
108  8  18
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed np.split before.

Comment: I think it should be noted that `np.split` only works when the `array` object is evenly divisible by the `N`. If it is not, it throws an error, as a result, I believe the better function to use is `np.array_split` which is the same as `np.split` but does not throw an error when the `array` is not evenly divisible by `N`.

Answer (score 9):

Based on your example `DataFrame`:

```
In [25]: df.index/3
Out[25]: Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64)

In [26]: for k,g in df.groupby(df.index/3):
    ...:     print k,g
    ...:     
0    a
0  1
1  2
2  3
1    a
3  4
4  5
5  6
2    a
6  7
7  8
8  9
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good answer for the example DataFrame and using groupby with a standard index. The larger DataFrames I work with tend to have a DateTimeIndex.

Comment: @seumas: In that case, you can call `df.reset_index()`, which will give you a dataframewhere with a linear index and where your previous DateTimeIndex becomes a column (unless you use `.reset_index(drop=True)`)